# Context menu does not display "add transform" in console job when using slow cheetah

Tags: visual-studio-2012, app-config, slowcheetah, config-transformation

I assume this is a simple fix considering I don't see any other posts about others having this issue.  I am using VS2012 and I added slowcheetah 2.5.10.3 to the project using the nuget package installer.

I have tried opening a new console application as well as a unit test project, but in both I am not able to "add transform" to my App.config.  The option in the context menu doesn't exist...

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You will need to install the [SlowCheetah Visual Studio extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) to get the additional menus in Visual Studio. The [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah/) only adds a `.targets` file to the solution which is useful for command line (build server) scenarios.

Comment: As I can remember, this wasn't necessary in previous versions of SlowCheetah. But good to get it working again :)

Comment: Note: I had to restart Visual Studio after doing this as well before Add Transform showed up in the menu.

Comment: Also can be installed by Tools->Extension Manager and Search the Online Gallery